# Is taking mean of `lambda.1se` from multiple runs of `cv.glmnet` a reasonable approach to dealing with the randomness of lambda?

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso, glmnet

So for `cv.glmnet` we get different values of lambda (lambda.min and lambda.1se) due to the randomness in how the data is split.

Is it reasonable to repeat `cv.glmnet` many times and take the mean value of Lambda.
Or would it be better to run `cv.glmnet` with LOOCV instead of 10-fold CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is reasonable. I don't think  lambda.1se adds anything.

For any cross validation metric it is recommended to run multiple cross validation runs.

Similarly how many folds is a generic problem.

However I would point out your reasoning is wrong: loo has high variance and low bias, basically because the estimators are so correlated, so noise doesn't cancel out.
Low bias because we are estimating test error for model with n data points with model with n-1.

Page 242 of elements of statistical learning (available online)

> What value should we choose for K? With K = N, the cross-validation estimator is approximately unbiased for the true (expected) prediction error, but can have high variance because the N “training sets”are so similar to one another. The computational burden is also considerable, requiring N applications of the learning method. In certain special problems, this computation can be done quickly

Comment: Ok thanks, and what do you mean by lambda.1se doesn't add anything.

Comment: that there is nothing specific about lambda.1se, the question is generic - how to estimate a metric using crossvalidation